# How to suppress error: Access of possibly undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I embed two swf files on my page:

```html
<embed src="first.swf" ... >
<embed src="second.swf" ... >
```

In first I have class named Base.
But when I access it in second.swf I can't compile it:

```
Base.doSomeStuff();
```

```
Error: Access of possibly undefined property
```

How to suppress this error?

I don't really know how to do this but use Loader or something like that isn't my way.

Comment: SWFs don't share classes just because they are on the same page. They don't share anything else either, they cannot access each other's scope, etc. Everything you use in the **second.swf** must be either initially compiled into it or loaded into it at runtime. There are no other options.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you should put this as an answer. So how can I share their data? Is the only way to do it to use the Loader class?

Comment: @Organis If I load an swf using "Loader" may it access parent's classes? I don't want to use Loader, because one my swf is invisible and I want it to only run code.

Comment: I found "_global" object. I think it's solution but I'm not sure.

Comment: As I said earlier, there are no ways to "share" data between two Flash applications (two SWFs in one page are them). The **_global** thing is a top-level object container for all the data and classes inside a single Flash application, but it is not a shared scope for all the running Flash application either. I think it's high time you described what are you actually trying to achieve there. It seems to me you were solving some problem, came up with a solution, and now you are trying to implement that solution but having problems doing so, all because the solution was wrong in the first place.

Comment: @Organis I tried to use ActionScript2, because I want to modify very old flash game, but in FlashDevelop when I import "flash.external.ExternalInterface" the compiler doesn't recognize it and keep giving me "undefined variable" error.

Comment: Because the **ExternalInterface** class belongs to **AS3**. It didn't exist back in **AS2**. Again, I advise you to explain what you are tried to achieve. Bacause whatever it is, resorting to earlier versions of **ActionScript** doesn't solve problems but rather stackpiles lots of new ones.

Comment: @Organis I bet that I saw AS2 project that uses ExternalInterface. I try to modify an old flash game. It's written in AS2. I can provide you swf or source code.

Comment: The game reffers to ExternalInterface by `flash.external.ExternalInterface`.

Comment: Oh, ok, I stand corrected: https://open-flash.github.io/mirrors/as2-language-reference/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: @Organis But why doesn't it import? I just get `Error: undefined variable`. I import it like this: `import flash.externalExternalInterface;`. Other imports don't work either.

Comment: No idea, I never worked with **AS2** in **FlashDevelop**. You probably need to set something up, who knows. I advise using **AS3**. It is faster, has more capabilities, and also has integrity the former ones lack. Also, **AS3** is much (really much) better documented.

Comment: @Organis Thank you for your help I just had to switch platform from "Custom" to "Flash Player".